# Is there any way of locking parts of code from deletion in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

If someone has several classes with thousands of lines of code is there any case of locking them or part of them, so not to delete some part by accident?

Comment: No. Use VCS to spot unwanted changes in code.

Comment: you should check out repository

Answer (score 2):

You can lock a file by clicking the padlock at bottom-right. If you try to modify it, you will be notified. Obviously, it only works locally. Use always VCS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> part of them, so not to delete some part by accident

`There are two kinds of computer users: those who do backup, and those who will`

You can (and should) use version control like Git, SVN so in case of accidental removal you can retrieve last copy from your repo. And even if not there's always `Undo` in `Edit` menu that works with deletion too. You can also make file  "read-only" by using padlock icon located in bottom right corner. Yet this is not bullet proof solution and deletion is not always to worse thing that can happen so again - use version control system for your code.